# Devise authentication gem: How to save the logged in user id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using the Devise Ruby gem in my Ruby on Rails 3 application. When a logged in user creates one of my models, I want to save their user id as the person who created it. What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a migration file with a column of type `integer` named `user_id`, this is where the association will be stored. (see the [migration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for details on how to do this).
2. in your model, add: `belongs_to :user` (see the [associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more details)
3. in the controller for your model, add `@your_model.user = current_user` in the create action. This will do the association you're looking for.  (`current_user` is a method provided by devise that returns the User ActiveRecord for the currently logged in user)

**Note:** there are more than one way of doing the actual association. I'm suggesting to do it in the controller but it could be done in the model or elsewhere.

Comment: wouldn't it be safer or more adherent to mvc that the model took care of it? how would you implement that ?

Comment: There's a number of way to do it in the model. One of them would be to use the before_create (see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to force the association with current_user.