# @mymodel.user = current_user is not working for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I followed these questions([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766239/devise-authentication-gem-how-to-save-the-logged-in-user-id) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009295/devise-how-to-associate-current-user-to-post)) on how to adjust my methods with the current user only so they have the specific user_id to edit,update, create and destroy their products.

Here is my code:

My Migration:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.date :date
      t.decimal  :price, :default => 0, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
      t.integer :user_id
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude
```

the Controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @products = Product.all

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

  def new
   @product = Product.new

  def edit
    @product.user = current_user
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @product.user = current_user
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

  def update
    @product.user = current_user
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])


  def destroy
    @product.user = current_user
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
```

Product Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :date, :price, :tag_list 
    belongs_to :user
end
```

then the Devise User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me 

  has_many :products,        :dependent => :destroy
```

I try to submit it and then suddenly this pops up:

**NoMethodError in ProductsController#create**

```
undefined method `user=' for nil:NilClass
```

**What am i missing or doing wrong?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign @product.user before you have a product. Do your find on the product first, then assign the user.

```
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@product.user = current_user
```

For the actions other than create where you want to restrict the product to the current_user, you can do something like this (assuming you setup the `has_many :products` association in your `User` model.

```
@product = current_user.products.find(params[:id])
```

That will restrict find to just those products that have the user_id equal to the current_user.

Comment: Oh wow didn't know the order mattered! I thought all actions get produced at the same time. This works and i can create it but i can still as other users, destroy and edit other users products. How do i correct this?

Comment: See the additions to my answer.